# gcc __attribute__((selectany)) alternative for linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, multiple-definition-error

i would like to know if there is an alternative for `__attribute__((selectany))` in linux ?

i would like to define something like that:

```
char * a[] = { "qwe", "zxc" };
```

in a header file and include it in many .c files which would be linked together.
so the linker will see more than one definition of "a" and therefor will not link. i've read of this attribute (selectany), which will use only the first seen definition of "a", unfortunately it is only for ms windows.
so the question is: is there an alternative method in linux ?

**edit**: the actual question is: is there a way to instruct the linker to use only the first seen definition and ignore any other perhaps even if they are different ?
i know there are many ways to define my data, i'm not searching for solution of how to define my data, instead i would like to know if there is a way to have multiple definitions and make the linker work with the first seen...

Comment: This is interesting, could you share what you are trying to ultimately accomplish? I understand the question, I'm just curious after reading it.

Comment: i have an enum with some types (ex: STRING, INTEGER, FLOAT, etc...). as you know the values of the types are integer... i needed a string representations of the types so here comes the   char * type_names[] = { [STRING] = "string", ...}, but as you can imagine i needed that definition near the enumerator in the header file, so i made it static const char * [], with #ifdef INCLUDE_TYPE_NAMES around it, but i was curious if there is a way to accomplish it in the described (in the question) way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for the 'weak' gcc attribute.

Comment: This answers the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should definitively give it a `const` attribute:

```
char const * a[] = { "qwe", "zxc" };
```

modifying string literals would lead to undefined behavior. Then to answer your question, at least partially.

Besides the approach of declaring it `extern` as in previous answers, the first, not recommended, way to proceed would be to declare your array `static`. You'd then have a copy of the array in each compilation unit that uses the array. As long as you don't want to modify the contents of the arrays (have the pointers point to different strings) this is fine, but blows up your code a bit.

If you'd just need to reference the strings in function scope and you have a C99 complying compiler you could look into using *compound literals*:

```
#define MYARRAY ((char const*const[]){ "qwe", "zxc" })
```

This you could then use *readonly* as you would expect, something like `MYARRAY[1]` and any decent compiler should be able to optimize such an access.

Comment: I was going to suggest just declaring them static, but I think the OP wants the linker to ignore all but the first definition of 'a'.

Comment: yes, this was my first idea, defining it as const and static, but as you mentioned it will make just as much copies as many object files (units) i have, which is not good if data is big and object files are many... but it is the only way i was able to link multiple definitions of the data, still not just one definition.        as for the second suggestion it seems a good idea, if the compiler really optimizes it to just one copy, i'll give it a try, thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply declare it in the header, and provide a single definition in one translation unit?

Answer (score 0):

What about declaring in the header as:

```
extern char * a[] = { ... }
```

And then define the actual a[] in only one c file:

```
char * a[] = { ... }
```

Comment: @Blagovest, it's not good idea yes, but still if you want to keep multiple data types in sync...  i know there are many solutions, but is there an attribute or other method to instruct the linker to use only one definition when there are multiple ?

Comment: Yes. When you declare a variable as 'extern', the compiler ensures that it will look for the concrete variable's memory location in only once place, and all references will point to the same object.

Comment: Hmmm, I see.  gcc has an argument called -multiply_defined.  Have you tried that to see if it works?

Comment: @Misk, it seems -multiply_defined  is only for darwin, and i cannot find documentation of it... even more - it is not recognized on linux gcc... but thanks for the try.