# How do you store duplicate constant strings in a single pointer while still being able to know its length at compile time?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, gcc

I would like to find a way to store duplicate constant strings in a single location. However; I need to get the length of that string at the compiler level (such that it is not found at runtime by functions such as strlen()). I know of a way to do each of these separately, as shown.

Storing duplicate strings in a single address by using pointers:

```
const char *a = "Hello world.";
const char *b = "Hello world.";
printf("a %s b\n", a == b ? "==" : "!="); // Outputs "a == b" on GCC
```

Getting the length of a string at compile time:

```
const char c[] = "Hello world.";
printf("Length of c: %d\n", sizeof(c) - 1); // Outputs 12 on GCC
```

Though there seems to be no way to combine the two:

```
const char *d = "Hello world.";
printf("Length of d: %d\n", sizeof(d)); // Outputs the size of the pointer type; 8 on 64-bit computers

const char e[] = "Hello world.";
const char f[] = "Hello world.";
printf("e %s f\n", e == f ? "==" : "!="); // Outputs "e != f" on GCC

const char *g[] = {"Hello world."};
const char *h[] = {"Hello world."};
printf("g %s h\n", g == h ? "==" : "!="); // Outputs "g != h"
printf("Length of g: %d\n", sizeof(g[0])); // Outputs pointer type size
```

Is there a way to do this that I am unaware of?

Comment: Why do you have these needs—what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I am writing a library that may have duplicate strings within files that are labeled as “static const char”. I much prefer using compile-time generated string lengths so that if there was a string 1,000 characters long, you wouldn’t have to wait for a 1,000 character search using strlen(), as you would just have a constant value for how long that string is. I would also not like to have duplicate strings because they are redundant, but I’d much prefer not having a file dedicated to storing every string for every class.

Comment: Just write a separate program that organizes the strings and their sizes however you want and writes a `.c` file defining them and a `.h` file exporting declarations. The C compiler was not intended to do much compile-time data preparation, and there is little reason to try to kludge it into doing so when one can readily write a special-purpose program to do the desired work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcc \_\_attribute\_\_((selectany)) alternative for linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826612/gcc-attribute-selectany-alternative-for-linux)

Comment: C does not guarantee that equal string literals share space, although GCC normally performs that optimisation. Other compilers might not. And if the literals are in different translation units, you also need linker support.

Comment: Also, you might consider `const char *const d = "Hello, world";`, if you want to make it easier for the compiler to constant-fold `strlen(d)`.

Comment: @rici I know this isn’t a C language standard, which is why I tagged it GCC. And thank you for that advice. I was under the assumption that a constant character array with a variable pointer would be enough, but there’s no reason not to have a constant pointer as well.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I’ll end up doing this if there is no other way, but it just seems very inelegant to write every string in a single file that every class must include. Though I suppose we can’t always get the best of both worlds. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc may be able to optimize the strlen() call to get the length at compile time.
Check the `-foptimize-strlen` option here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Is there any info on what this actually does to compiled code? I’ll have a look at it in the morning if not, but it says it uses the functions’ “faster alternatives”, which leads me to believe they just use different functions. Furthermore the option “ max-tracked-strlens” says it sets the maximum “strlen optimization pass[es] [that] will track string lengths”, which seems to be an alternative function to store lengths. If it equivalent to a compile-time constant, this is the solution.

Comment: Didn't find any official info, but there's this [blogpost](https://shintakezou.blogspot.com/2017/03/length-at-compile-time.html) which suggests the call to strlen() is replaced with an assembly mov operation with the constant length, I guess it may also depend on the version of the compiler, so you should check the assembly it generates for you.

Comment: This seemed to work well in GCC in the tests I did. The only issue is that it forces you to include string.h, even though no call to strlen() is made. This is not a problem for my use, but maybe something to note for those looking into it. The blogpost given was very descriptive and worth reading.